# ffmpeg: remove cover picture from mp3/convert to ogg without cover

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two questions on working with ffmpeg:

1) how to remove cover picture from mp3
2) if there is a cover in mp3, how to say ffmpeg to convert it to ogg without picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this sir

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -q 1 -map a a.ogg
```

[**ref**](http://svnpenn.github.com/2012/ffmpeg-encode-mp3)

Comment: Link is dead, an explanation would be nice

Comment: Since they didn't give explanation in 6 years I will.. The "-map a" option just says only take audio streams from input and copy them out to new file with ogg format (indicated by .ogg extension). Ignoring mapping the "cover" stream (which is a "v" stream) will remove it.